# Why have all files in Flutter project red? And why I see a blank screen when I run the code?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax-error, scrollview, flutter-pageview

I have made a project with Flutter and everything was going fine until I closed my project and when I opened it: I see that all files have turned red and I cannot view anything on the emulator but a white screen (but the first page works just fine).

[This is the image of all files turning red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv7cL.png)

Then, when I run one of the pages, I see a blank screen and a Failed Assertion error: hasSize
I'm unaware of these problems.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not added them to your git repository that's why.

Comment: as @SaaranshMenon said you havent added your files to git, if you want to remove git from your project delete `.git` folder in your root project.